# Xcode unable to build

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, build

Yesterday at night I was able to build my project on my phone or simulator but now I'm unable because Xcode is using all the memory of my computer, i don't know what the problem is but yesterday I was able to build and today I'm not and my computer is really slow, I get no errors but it simply wont build, I've tried cleaning, restarting my computer, running the terminal, etc. None have worked

Comment: How much memory do you have? What does Activity Monitor say?

Comment: 4, activity monitor in the memory tab: the square with the rating becomes red and a swift process is the one consuming all the memory, sorry for the lack of details I'm not home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my last two contracts I was given a mini with 4GB and that is not enough, you will be paging memory and that will make Xcode basically unusable. I upgraded to 16GB and the system was usable.

In the Activity Monitor Application, not in Xcode, look at "Swap Used"; if it is not 0 and you do not have other apps running there is not sufficient memory.

My advice: get 16GB, 8GB is a bare minimum for development. 4GB can work but also can by so slow as to be unusable.

Comment: Thanks, ill get an upgrade

Comment: @Robotic Cat Thanks! I grew up in a KB world.

Comment: Where can i get this upgrade??

Comment: What kind of a Mc do you have, not all can be upgraded. Personally I use [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com).

Comment: A Mac mini, the small one